# Possibilities to extend the definition of a smooth function on an open set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, derivatives

Consider the function $F:A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

If $A$ is open, then the standard definition, of what it means for $f$ to be  a  "smooth function" can be found in every textbook.

But now consider the following excerpt:

[image]

This is on way to generalize the concept of "smooth function" to arbitrary domains. Contrast that with:

[image]

Wouldn't it be also possible to generalize the concept of "smooth function" in a different way than mentioned in the top scan, such that we would call a function on a domain "smooth" if there exists something like and "inward differential" ?

Or would these two possible definitions coincide on domains, where both of them can be applied ?

Comment: I would guess the second "generalisation" would be much weaker than the first one and hence wouldn't be very useful in practice, because the existence of directional derivatives is indeed much weaker than differentiability at a certain point. Pitifully I don't currently have any illustrating example at hand.

Comment: @Vim If you do happen to find an example, do let me know, you could make a partial answer and get some upvotes.